# Powershell Active directory user update

Tags: powershell

Im trying to update the -msDS-cloudExtensionAttribute's of all users in a CSV.

CSV example

```
AD  CA11    CA10    CA9
User1   none    none    technician
User2   none    engineer    technician
User3   responsible engineer    technician
User4   none    none    none
User5   none    none    none
User6   responsible none    technician
User7   none    none    none
User8   none    engineer    none
User9   none    none    none
User10  none    none    technician
```

Im using set-ADUSer, but it does not recognise the attributes.

```
Import-CSV c:\temp\all.csv | Foreach { Set-ADUSer -Identity $_.AD -Add -msDS-cloudExtensionAttribute10 $_.CA10 -msDS-cloudExtensionAttribute11 $_.CA11 -msDS-cloudExtensionAttribute9 $_.CA9 }
```

error:

```
A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'msDS-cloudExtensionAttribute10'
```

I've also tried adding -Add to the command, but then I get a different error.

```
Missing an argument for parameter 'Add'. Specify a parameter of type 'System.Collections.Hashtable'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that `Set-ADUser` doesn't have explicit parameters defined for every possible attribute you can set. Instead, you've got parameters like `-Add` and `-Replace` that take a hash table of key/value pairs.

In your case, I'd probably use `-Replace` kind of like this.

```
$csv = Import-CSV C:\temp\all.csv
$csv | foreach { 
    Set-ADUser $_.AD -Replace @{'msDS-cloudExtensionAttribute10'=$_.CA10; 'msDS-cloudExtensionAttribute11'=$_.CA11; 'msDS-cloudExtensionAttribute9'=$_.CA9}
}
```